# Why is my python code printing this weird pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve the following pattern:
[image]

And here is the code that I wrote:

```
limit = 10
for i in range(1, 12):
    for j in range(i):
        print(" "*j, end="")

    if limit >= 0:
        for j in range(0, limit):
            print(j, end="")

    limit -= 1
    print()
```

But it is printing this weird pattern:

[image]

Comment: You are not printing `j` spaces, you are printing `j` times `j` spaces.  You don't need BOTH the `" "*j` and the `for j in range(i)`.  One or the other.  By the way, I believe you need to have a space in between each of those digits.

Comment: Where the code says `for j in range(i): print(" "*j, end="")`, how many spaces do you think this should print? Why? (Hint: how many times will the loop run? How many spaces will it print the first time? The second time? etc.?)

Comment: thanks it got the solution
'''
limit = 10
for i in range(1, 12):
    print(" "*i, end="")

    if limit >= 0:
        for j in range(0, limit):
            print(j, end=" ")

    limit -= 1
    print()
'''
This worked perfectly

Answer (score 4):

You can unpack a list of an incrementing number of spaces and a decrementing range of numbers as arguments for the `print` function:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(*[' '] * i, *range(10 - i))
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw9BA04pLAQgKijLzSjS0otUV1GMVtBQydRS0YCoUdBUyNTX//wcA)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the help.
I did the following change:

```
limit = 10
for i in range(1, 12):
    print(" "*i, end="")

    if limit >= 0:
        for j in range(0, limit):
            print(j, end="")

    limit -= 1
    print()
```

This worked perfectly.

Comment: Just for info on formatting your answer, you should use `\`` instead of `'` to format code block.

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this question in these 2 lines:

```
for item in range(10):
    print("  " * item + " ".join([str(x) for x in range(10 - item)]))
```

This problem might be caused by the inconsistencies in the nested loop. You should not have created a nested loop in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be implemented in a much simpler way. You do not need the `limit` variable and also reduce the number of magic numbers you use in your code to make it more understandable.

Code:

```
# Loop for rows
for i in range(10):
    # Loop for columns
    for j in range(10):
        # Decide what to print
        temp = f'{j - i}' if j - i >= 0 else ' '
        print(temp, end=" ")
    print()
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
        0 1 2 3 4 5 
          0 1 2 3 4 
            0 1 2 3 
              0 1 2 
                0 1 
                  0
```

So, imagine you want to print a 10x10 grid of numbers. You'll need two loops of `10`. To get the pattern, you want the difference between the column index and the row index and print it only when the difference value is greater than or equal to `0` otherwise print a space in its place. The above code does that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this,

```
limit = 10
for i in range(limit, -1, -1):
    print(" " * ((limit - i)*2) + " ".join(f"{j}" for j in range(i)))
          #      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          # To calculate the spaces
```

---

**Output:**

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6
        0 1 2 3 4 5
          0 1 2 3 4
            0 1 2 3
              0 1 2
                0 1
                  0
```